# Android beacon library: how to disable run at startup

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon

It seems that importing android beacon library (2.9) aar file force an application to have "run at startup" permission (adds a receiver in the manifest: org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver)

A test app who wants detect beacon when in foreground only and do not needs run at startup can disable it (and avoid to ask user for the run at startup permission)?

Comment: Would you please reformulate your question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the Android Beacon Library will start background scanning at startup of the phone, but *only* if your app constructs a `RegionBootstrap` object in a the `onCreate` method of a custom Application class.  This feature is not new as of 2.9 -- it has been around since 2.0.    You can read about how this works [here.](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html)

There are two ways to disable this behavior, depending on the specifics of what you want to disable:

1. If you simply do not want the library to scan for beacons on phone startup, simply do not construct a `RegionBootstrap`.
2. The library's manifest automatically adds a request for RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED to the manifest to enable scanning at startup.   If you don't want this to happen, simply add this line to your app's manifest to keep it from getting merged in:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" tools:node="remove" />
   ```

Comment: I want avoid asking users the "run at startup" permission (not necessary to the app). The first way you suggest do not solve it (but changing BootstrapNotifier with MonitorNotifier is a goog idea: I applied it). Trying the second way you suggest "tools:" is not recognized.

Comment: Added tool namespace and "tools" recognized. But still app requires "run at startup" :-(

Comment: If you have ` tools:node="remove"` applied properly the app will not require run at startup.  Something must be wrong.  To see your final merged manifest, check in `app/build/intermefests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and see if the BOOT_COMPLETED entry is not there.  It should not be.  Try doing a clean and rebuild.

Comment: The line copied (not easy with scroll bar) became `<permission andro...>` accepted from compiler but not working, of course. Correcting the mispelled `uses-permission` finally works. Many thanks to davidgyoung

Comment: Glad it works!  Please mark the answer as accepted so it will be easy for other folks who have the same problem to find the solution.